# Having trouble getting Bootstrap nested rows/columns to line up correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to get some nested rows/columns to line up with the rest of the layout properly, but it's not working. I've tried all sorts of margin and padding style tweaks, but there's always extra space under the top row. It'll be pretty obvious what I'm trying to do once you see the layout.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="row full-gutter">
          <div class="col-md-6 min-gutter">
            <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 min-gutter">
            <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row full-gutter">
          <div class="col-md-12 min-gutter">
            <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 min-gutter">
        <div class="img-placeholder-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Styles:

```
.no-gutter {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0; }
.min-gutter {
    padding-right:5px!important;
    padding-left:5px!important; }
.full-gutter {
    padding-right:10px!important;
    padding-left:10px!important; }
.img-placeholder-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 0; }
.img-placeholder-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 0 0; }
```

Test link here: http://designatwork.net/precision/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting your page you see that one extra `<p>` tag is coming that is the reason extra space is coming under the top row. In Wordpress some times we will face this problem so either you can remove those extra `<p>` tags or you can add this css for second row to remove space.

```css
element.style {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px !important;
}
```